# shell script having embedded password inside it is not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, centos

I have developed a shell script whose job is to take the dump of postgres DB. Below is the snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
yes "password" | sudo -S sudo su - postgres <<EOF
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_dump -U postgres -d db_name > /home/db_backup/db_name_$today.sql
EOF
exit
```

However, this script is NOT running because of the below reason:

```
[sudo] password for user: Sorry, Try again
```

However, when I use `sudo su - postgres` and then provide password, it is working as expected. And interestingly, if now I run the above shell script after the login, it runs absolutely fine.

What I am missing here.

Comment: You are trying to provide input to the `sudo` command with both a pipe (from `yes`) *and* a here-document (the `<<EOF` part). It can only have one input (and in this case, the here-document is overriding the pipe).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: so I should put `EOF` instead of `yes`? Can you please elaborate a little? Sorry I am a beginner in CentOS hence asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is dangerous to store passwords in scripts, so please do not do it.

Modify your `/etc/sudoers` file by running `sudo visudo` and adding a line like this at the bottom:

```
%sudo   ALL=(postgres) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/psql
```

This allows anyone with sudo permission to run `/usr/bin/psql` to postgres on any host (ALL) with no password.

Now your script should work this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
sudo -b -n -H -u postgres /usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_dump -U postgres -d db_name > /home/db_backup/db_name_$today.sql
```

Make sure postgres can write to the directory `/home/db_backup/`.